# Snow in the nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So i was wondering since one of the recent updates brought the possibility of crafting snow panels. This allows you to re-create a snowy biome. Now I was wondering what happens to the snow if you place it in the nether? I then also realised that i never tried placing snow blocks in the nether. Has anyone tested this yet? A link to a wiki would also be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have to be a specific wiki or does any suffice?

Comment: No any source stating that you can or cant place snow in the nether would be fine

Comment: Sorry, I have to downvote for lack of research. Finding the answer to this by trying it would have taken less time than posting the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed place snow bocks and snow panels in the nether. both in creative and survival. (you can also throw snowballs)
[image]

Comment: Minecraft Logic: Water evaporates in the nether, snow stays frozen....

Comment: yep thats what i've been saying; minecraft is the most realistic game ever...

Comment: Hmm interesting, do snowballs do extra damage (or any damage at all) against nether mobs then?

Comment: Snowballs dont do any damage to any mobs exept blazes

Comment: @RustyMembers They do damage to the Ender dragon as well.